# Element won't hide - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have several wrappers which contain a loading gif while the real image loads.

I also have some jquery that is supposed to hide the gif once the real image loads, but the loading gif doesn't hide. If I replace $(this) with $(".displayImg") it will work, but it will affect all the loading gifs. Why does $(this) make it not hide?

```js
$('.displayImg').on("load", function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".loadingImage").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <img class='loadingImage' src='https://media0.giphy.com/media/xTk9ZvMnbIiIew7IpW/giphy.gif'>

  <img class='displayImg' src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <img class='loadingImage' src='https://media0.giphy.com/media/xTk9ZvMnbIiIew7IpW/giphy.gif'>

  <img class='displayImg' src='https://via.placeholder.com/200x100'>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code has some syntax issues but actually runs just fine. I edited your question and turned it into a running snippet. I had to add jQuery dependency, are you sure jQuery is loaded in your project? (Clear your cache to see the loader each time you run this snippet.)

Comment: Are you sure the load handler is running for all the images? Add `console.log(this.src);` and check if you see messages for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine but you can improve it like this:

```
$('.displayImg').on("load", function() {
  $(this).prev(".loadingImage").hide();
});
```

Comment: An improvement would be using `.closest()` and than back up the DOM tree using `.find()`. Your suggestion is brittle and error prone as soon a HTML sibling is added or more nesting inserted. Looks more like a comment, or an answer better suited for sites like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Javascript at all. One way is to put loader as a background image. When the actual image loads (assuming it doesn't have any transparency) it will cover the loader. And you can resize and position the loader however you like.

```css
.wrapper1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(https://media0.giphy.com/media/xTk9ZvMnbIiIew7IpW/giphy.gif);
}

.wrapper2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://media0.giphy.com/media/xTk9ZvMnbIiIew7IpW/giphy.gif);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper1'>
  <img class='displayImg' src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
</div>

<div class='wrapper2'>
  <img class='displayImg' src='https://via.placeholder.com/200x100'>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not adding the loading gif as `background-image` for the `<img>` tag itself? If the `src` is a transparent PNG (like you correctly noticed) some JS would still be fine to remove the unnecessary spinner.